# Facebook Login redirect URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I've checked almost all top answers on this topic and nothing had worked. I am sure, my redirect url is set in control panel.

My redirect URL:

> https://m.facebook.com/v3.1/dialog/oauth?redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fapi-dev.yourlastbigthing.com%2Fapi%2Ftrainees%2Fsocial%2Ffb%2Fcallback&state=beu6qjlfa0pjfm6atiog&scope=email+user_friends+user_photos+groups_access_member_info+publish_to_groups+user_age_range+user_birthday+user_events+user_gender+user_hometown+user_likes+user_link+user_location+user_posts+user_tagged_places+user_videos&response_type=code&client_id=1063808107120820

My Facebook application settings:

[image]

Still getting Error

[image]

Looks like I am missing something important. I've tried to change all of the switches in control panel, but nothings changes.

Some additional settings:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks ok. Can you show your basic app settings as well - app domains and the settings for the website platform?

Comment: @misorude provided

Comment: So is this supposed to be a desktop app, or is that just checked due to your trial and error? If you want login on the web to work, then you need to set up the Website platform.

Comment: @misorude it is some random configuration, was just checking. I've changed - still error.

Comment: And did you set up the Website platform by now, or …?

Comment: @misorude where exactly should I set it up?

Comment: Settings -> Basic.

Comment: @misorude added https://api-dev.yourlastbigthing.com/ as website, still error

Comment: Have you removed the desktop app settings?

Comment: @misorude yes, I did

Comment: @misorude check my answer just in case. Ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

OOOOK, Facebook.

> https://www.sample.com - **not valid**
>
> https://www.sample.com/ - **valid**

hope it helps someone

Comment: Haha :-) Which part, the redirect URIs, or something else? I remember they had something like that back in the day for canvas apps, but never encountered it in relation to login settings.